# It is possible to register a name in ENS (Ethereum Name Service) from Mist Wallet?

Tags: mist, ens

I want to register a name in ENS, but I have only done it from MyEtherWallet because everything is built-in.

But now I want to use an address I have in Mist. It is possible to register a name in ENS (Ethereum Name Service) from Mist Wallet?

Answer (score 0):

From [ENC documentation](http://ens.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#which-wallets-and-dapps-support-ens-so-far).

> **Which wallets and DApps support ENS so far?** 
> MyEtherWallet supports
>   both registering names via the auction process and sending funds and
>   interacting with contracts identified by their names.
>
> Metamask supports sending funds to ENS names.
>
> **Mist is working on ENS support and should announce it soon.**
>
> LEth is working on ENS support and should announce it soon.
>
> Status is working on ENS support and should announce it soon.